# Bluemix Securegatway Installation Error on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

Installation goes through fine but we keep on getting this error message once launching the client's UI:

[image]

```
The command is: node lib\secgwclient.js cEm9COT0o411_prod_ng --1 INFO --P 9003 module.js:457 
    throw err; 

Error: Cannot find module 'log4js' 
    at Function.Module.resolveFilename (module.js:455:15) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25) 
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17) at require (internal/module.js:20:19) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client\lib\utils\logging.js:26:18) 
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10) 
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32) 
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

The error is complaining about log4js module `Cannot find log4js module`. I tried manually installing the log4js modue using npm, but the error persists.

Comment: Please do not post images of errors. We can't copy them, the SO Search can't find them, and if the link changes your question will no longer make sense. Copy the error message, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14362827) your question and paste the message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually indicates that the install is behind a firewall or proxy which caused the npm install to fail. Does the machine have outbound access to npmjs.com:443?

You can either re-install the client or run `npm install` from the client folder.  If npm is not a globally recognized command, you will need to provide the path to npm that is packaged with the node version contained within the installation folder.